# Append the HTML tag to the document. HierarchyRequestError: The operation would yield an incorrect node tree

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I was testing my React/TypeScript project with Jest + Enzyme.

When I created an HTML tag and appended it to the document, I got an error. This was the unit test code that produced the error:

```
const htmlTag: HTMLElement = document.createElement('html');
htmlTag.setAttribute('myAttribute', 'myValue');
document.appendChild(htmlTag); // HierarchyRequestError: The operation would yield an incorrect node tree
```

So Jest didn't like something about adding an HTML tag to the document. [A similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766181/hierarchyrequesterror-failed-to-execute-appendchild-on-node) implies that what I am trying to do is not possible, but since I need to test what my code does to a particular HTML attribute, how else would I test that?

**Is there a better way to add the HTML tag to the document so that I can test its attributes later?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way to add the HTML tag to the document so that I can test its attributes later?

The HTML tag didn't need to be added. I just "got" it!

```
const htmlTag = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]; // The html tag is still attached to the DOM
```

Now I can set or test its attributes per [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57581707/5587356).